# WP is not using the select custom template.php that its selected for a page

Tags: pages, templates, child-theme

I created a childtheme: Fisio

Inside I have: page-team.php with the name:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Page - Team
*/
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<script>alert('its the team page')</script>
```

And in the wp-admin I selected it for the page: Team

[image: Please check the page name and the selected template]

The problem is that any changes I make to page-team.php are not affected. In fact, the alert is never executed.

What am I missing?

PD: Is there a way to know wich was the template used having a look to the source code? I can't find this

-EDIT-

forgot to mention that team is listing a custom post_type: team, here is the declaration in functions.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Custom Post type register framework
 */
include(get_stylesheet_directory(). '/inc/acpt/init.php');
add_action('init', 'makethem');
function makethem() {
    $args = array(
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'page-attributes', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt'  ),
        'hierarchical' => true,
    );

    $team = new post_type('team','team', false,  $args );

}

/**
 * Initialize the metabox class
 */
add_action( 'init', 'be_initialize_team_meta_boxes', 9999 );
function be_initialize_team_meta_boxes() {
    if ( !class_exists( 'team_Meta_Box' ) ) {
        require_once( get_stylesheet_directory(). '/inc/metaboxes/fisio-metaboxes.php' );
        require_once( get_stylesheet_directory(). '/inc/metaboxes/init.php' );

    }
}
?>
```

Comment: have you save changes after you selected new template for a page?

Comment: Yes I Did. It did not return any error or warning and the template its still selected in the page settings. Any thoughts?

Comment: I checked your code and its working fine. can you just show me which classes are gets added to body tag in front end?

Comment: Hello @VinodDalvi Thanks for your comment but I'm not sure i'm following you. If you mean the class attr to the body is: "archive post-type-archive post-type-archive-team logged-in admin-bar  customize-support"

Comment: Yes I have, I will add the declaration to the question. Thats right its in maintenance mode i don't think i'm allowed to share it..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have created custom post type named team so it is displaying archive of custom post type team on the team page try changing slug of team page from team to team2 or something else but not team.

Visit [this page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) to learn more about how wordpress handles templates.

Comment: You are a genius. Saved my hair from falling out.